# Jenkins parallel pipeline: All subroutine calls in parameter blocks pass arguments from last block

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parallel-processing, closures, jenkins-pipeline

I am asking for help understanding what is going on with a Groovy closure and what the "right" way to do something is.  I have a Jenkins pipeline where I am calling a subroutine in 5 parallel branches; it takes one parameter whose actual value is a string constant - a different one in each call from a parallel branch.  What I am seeing is that all 5 executions are receiving the string constant named in the last parallel branch:

Snippet:

```
def build_if_needed = { project ->
  println "build_if_needed: $project"
  // ultimately this will kick off a build job...
}

parallel (
  aaa : { build_if_needed('aaa')},
  bbb : { build_if_needed('bbb')},
  ccc : { build_if_needed('ccc')},
  ddd : { build_if_needed('ddd')},
  eee : { build_if_needed('eee')},
)
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [aaa] { (Branch: aaa)
[Pipeline] [bbb] { (Branch: bbb)
[Pipeline] [ccc] { (Branch: ccc)
[Pipeline] [ddd] { (Branch: ddd)
[Pipeline] [eee] { (Branch: eee)
[Pipeline] [aaa] echo
[aaa] build_if_needed: eee
[Pipeline] [aaa] }
[Pipeline] [bbb] echo
[bbb] build_if_needed: eee
[Pipeline] [bbb] }
[Pipeline] [ccc] echo
[ccc] build_if_needed: eee
[Pipeline] [ccc] }
[Pipeline] [ddd] echo
[ddd] build_if_needed: eee
[Pipeline] [ddd] }
[Pipeline] [eee] echo
[eee] build_if_needed: eee
[Pipeline] [eee] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

I am expecting the parameter value dumped in [aaa] to be 'aaa', not 'eee'.  It is a fixed string constant passed as a parameter.  Why are all 5 executions of 'build_if_needed' receiving the string constant from the final parallel invocation?  What am I missing?

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: I still don't understand the behavior shown above, but I was able to workaround it by following the logic in this post http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Generating-parallel-flow-with-Build-Flow-Plugin-td4687604.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was acknowledged as a bug in what was basically a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416854/jenkins-pipeline-shouldnt-closures-resolve-variables-the-same-inside-parallel).  It has been fixed as of Groovy Pipeline 2.35.

Answer (score 0):

It worked well in my case (Jenkins 2.7.4) to use method instead of closure:

```
def build_if_needed(project) {
  println "build_if_needed: $project"
  // ultimately this will kick off a build job...
}

parallel (
  aaa : { build_if_needed('aaa')},
  bbb : { build_if_needed('bbb')},
  ccc : { build_if_needed('ccc')},
  ddd : { build_if_needed('ddd')},
  eee : { build_if_needed('eee')}
)
```

In my experience, you should avoid using closures as much as you can in pipeline script.
Jenkins seems to have problems to handle closures like https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481.