# Jenkins Pipeline: Shouldn't closures resolve variables the same inside parallel as outside?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm experiencing some confusing behavior trying to execute code in a Jenkins pipeline script.  Values inside a closure take on some unexpected values.  I've seen references to a local variable trick that supposedly fixes this, but it is not working for me.

Simplified example: Create 3 jobs 'a', 'b', 'c' that print their argument - as passed in and as copied to a local.  First execute the jobs in parallel; then execute outside parallel to compare the result.  "say" is defined because println gives access exceptions in my Jenkins (I am not admin).

```
def say(s) {println(s)} // println gives exception inside create_jobs

def create_jobs() {
  def map = [:]                // needed for parallel
  def jobrunfn = { jobid ->    // return a closure that prints hello from job
    def pid = "$jobid"
    return {
      def xsay = { s -> say("[$pid] $s") }
      xsay "HELLO from $pid"
    }
  }

  map['a'] = jobrunfn('a')
  map['b'] = jobrunfn('b')
  map['c'] = jobrunfn('c')
  return map
}

def jobs = create_jobs()
parallel(jobs)              // for Jenkins pipeline only - not groovy interp
for (j in jobs) { jobs[j.key]() }   // groovy interp - parallel not available
```

The output - inside parallel, 'pid' is sometimes 'c', when it should be 'a' or 'b':

```
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [a] { (Branch: a)
[Pipeline] [b] { (Branch: b)
[Pipeline] [c] { (Branch: c)
[Pipeline] [a] echo
[a] [a] HELLO from c
[Pipeline] [a] }
[Pipeline] [b] echo
[b] [b] HELLO from c
[Pipeline] [b] }
[Pipeline] [c] echo
[c] [c] HELLO from c
[Pipeline] [c] }
[Pipeline] // parallel

[Pipeline] echo
[a] HELLO from a
[Pipeline] echo
[b] HELLO from b
[Pipeline] echo
[c] HELLO from c
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The argument is ALWAYS the last value passed in (not sure why, but it is consistent and I understand that you need the local variable trick.)

But, the local variable trick doesn't work consistently inside of parallel: even the local is sometimes 'c' (to the nested 'say' it gets it right, but the main body gets it wrong); outside of parallel it gets 'a' and 'b' as expected.

Am I misunderstanding?

Jenkins 2.32.2 on Linux, Pipeline:Grooby 2.27

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a pipeline's bug. See the [ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38268).

Comment: The bug claims that the absence of "node { }" clears the issue; I see the problem even without "node { }".  But I agree this is exactly what I'm seeing...  Thanks very much.

Comment: This test case is working now in Jenkins 2.46.3 with Groovy Pipeline 2.35.  Thanks very much to the Groovy Pipeline development team (looks like Andrew Bayer implemented the fix.)

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know this was a bug and I was storing things in a global-level "@Field" dictionary where each parallel branch had its own play area!

Comment: using list.each worked quite well.  I had avoided each closures because I thought they were classified as a pipeline problem.  thanks